# How do we annotate a variable to be of a type `object`, but annotate the individual properties as well?

Tags: typescript, object

In TypeScript, I am aware that we can define variables as `object` types, with the following.

```
let myObject: object;
myObject = { name: 'Khabib', age: 32 };
```

If I want to annotate the properties as well, I would do the following.

```
let myObject: { name: string; age: number };
myObject = { name: 'Khabib', age: 32 };
```

However, I did not annotate `myObject` explicitly as an `object`. How can I annotate `myObject: object` as well as the individual properties too? So, basically, how would I combine the following into one statement? Or is it not possible?

```
let myObject: object;
myObject: { name: string; age: number };
```

Comment: { } , doesn't it ensure its an object?

Comment: In vanilla JavaScript, I would have assumed the same. However, I have just started learning TypeScript, and it appears that I have the option of annotating a variable explicitly with `object`. So, I am just wondering how I would do the same when defining the property types.

Comment: In general, typescript is trying to get you _away_ from thinking about things as just "an object", and, instead, focus on the "shape" of the particular object you have in mind.  So for the most part, you want to just stick with your second definition, i.e., `{name: string; age: number}`.  That said you can define things more generically, but `object` is probably not the way you want to go.  Can you explain a little more what you are trying to achieve?  For example if you want to define a "generic" object with any properties, a useful way to do that is `Record<string,any>`, not `object`.

Comment: Aaah, okay! That's really insightful for me. Thanks!